# IE9: Access is denied when set up document.domain

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, same-origin-policy, cleditor

I have a problem when using document.domain with CLEditor on IE9. When I add document.domain I got error message "SCRIPT5: Access is denied.".  It works fine with Firefox and also when I remove document.domain. I still did not use cross sub-domain iframes, all iframes are in the same domain.

How to fix it without removing document.domain?

here is how I setup document.domain:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.domain = 'mydomain.com';
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cleditor.js"></script>
```

Here is a part of the CLEditor code where error apears:

```
      // Create a new iframe
    var $frame = editor.$frame = $('<iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:true;" id="iframe">')
      .hide()
      .appendTo($main);

    // Load the iframe document content
    var contentWindow = $frame[0].contentWindow,
      doc = editor.doc = contentWindow.document,     // here is the error message
      $doc = $(doc);
```

Here is the full source code of CLEditor:
    http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.js

Answer (score 0):

To use `document.domain`, it needs to be set to the same string on both sides of the communication -- here, set in both iFrame and parent.

Comment: I still did not start using iframes on different sub-domains. The iFrame and the parent are on the same sub-domain. both of them in the same domain and the same page. I think IE9 do not allow communication if the iFrame is created by JavaScript like this: var $frame = editor.$frame = $('<iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:true;" id="iframe">')